# dplyr not recognize the column

Tags: r, dplyr

I was doing something like this

```
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
painters %.%
  group_by(school) %.%
  mutate(Len = n()) %.%
  filter(Len > 6)
```

However, I got an error message:

> Error in painters %.% group_by(school) %.% mutate(Len = n()) %.% filter(Len >  : 
>     could not find function "%.%"

But school is a valid column in painters.

Totally new in R, please help. Thank you very much

Comment: Hint: As the error message suggests, it's an issue with the pipe function `%.%` you're using and not the data column.

Answer (score 1):

**Really *read*** what R is telling you:

> could not find function "%.%"

Which means that `%.%` is the problem. The correct pipe is `%>%`. The column has nothing to do with it.